# WAS7 message listener error, MQQueue incompatible wih MQDestination

Tags: listener, websphere-7, mq

while trying to startup one [message-listener-port](/questions/tagged/message-listener-port) in [was7](/questions/tagged/was7). I have checked all the `Connection factory JNDI` & `Destination JNDI` names, everything looks ok. And I can able to browse the queue in the terminal as well.

Pls help!

> [1/13/12 17:21:26:259 GMT+08:00] 00000029 MDBListenerIm W   WMSG0019E:
>   Unable to start MDB Listener ods, JMSDestination jms/quexx :
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue incompatible with
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination
>           at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createConnectionConsumer(MQConnection.java:210)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.createConnectionConsumer(JMSConnectionHandle.java:1272)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.createResources(MDBListenerImpl.java:542)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.internalStart(MDBListenerImpl.java:730)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.start(MDBListenerImpl.java:653)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerManagerImpl.start(MDBListenerManagerImpl.java:851)
>           at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MsgListenerPort.start(MsgListenerPort.java:317)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:816)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
>
> [1/13/12 17:21:26:264 GMT+08:00] 00000029 MDBListenerIm I   WMSG0043I:
>   MDB Listener lpquexx stopped for JMSDestination jms/quexx [1/13/12
>   17:21:26:266 GMT+08:00] 00000029 MDBListenerIm I   WMSG0058I: Listener
>   Port lpquexx will attempt to restart in 60 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a class loader issue, i.e. a class loaded by the container is clashing with a class loaded by your application.

Any chance you've accidentally included an MQ JAR somewhere in your app?